# Getting JSON reply from webservice

Tags: objective-c, json

i am trying to get only JSON response from a webservice. i am getting the below response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">[["123","testing123"]]</string>
```

which has XML. how can i get only JSON response. right now i am am getting parsing failed error. how can this be fixed. please help.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">[["123","testing123"]]</string>

Comment: Not sure how the xml tags got omited in the first post.

Comment: edit your post and include xml as code, check the editor toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
-(NSString *)removeWebserviceJunk:(NSString *)ws {
    NSString *withoutXMLPrologue = [ws stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r\n" withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [ws length])];
    return [withoutXMLPrologue stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".*<string .*>(.*)<\\/string>" withString:@"$1" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [withoutXMLPrologue length])];
}
```

And use SBJson (or other JSON library) to convert the resulting string to JSON.

Comment: the documentation for `NSRegularExpressionSearch` says that it only works with the `rangeOfString:...` methods